# svn+ssh hanging at 'svnserve -t'

Tags: ssh, vpn, svn, svnserve

We had a working svn server for the last months.  The connection is done via svn+ssh via a VPN.  Since some days, everyone working within the network is able to do every svn action, while some(!) people outside can only do check-ins.

I tried to debug the ssh connection from outside and everythingworks finde, except that it's a bit slow which isn't new.  When doing a `svn up`, the last output is

```
debug1: Sending command: svnserve -t"
```

After that, nothing happens forever until I quit the connection (I waited for some 10 minutes).

Does anyone has an idea what could be wrong or where to look next?

BTW with "double verbose" the last output is:

```
debug1: Sending command: svnserve -t
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 131072
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem with a specific repo now...

Answer (score 0):

If this is only for some people, or repos on some hosts:  we occasionally had trouble with the ssh part of the tunnel:

```
% ssh svnhost
The authenticity of host 'svnhost (192.168.2.100)' can't be established.
...
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

so we made it part of setting up new users to tell them to manually ssh and bail out after accepting the fingerprint.